# Next dev server automatically closes

Tags: next.js

I created a basic next.js application (both the nextjs-blog starter and just a generic nextjs application) and when I run "npm run dev," it appears to hang for a second before just closing the command. Going to localhost:3000 will only bring me to a screen that says "The site cannot be reached."

I have tried disabling firewall and there are no error messages.
I have followed the guides online and it gives me issues.
I have managed to start a standard vue3 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem when using nextjs 13.x I resolved by re-installing (instead of updating) the node version. And I notice that somehow my node architecture was 32 instead of 64. So worth to check your:

- Node architecture
- Node version

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by running `yarn install`, or the equivalent in NPM would probably work. Somehow the dependency tree has changed.